# Close screen / unmount screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) to navigate the screen in my react native app. I have one question, is it possible that when I close screen or unmount screen, the rendered content are kept and not destroyed. So the next time when I call the screen again, the rendered content should not be reloaded again. Or maybe there is another way to achieve this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should try redux and get your states from your reducers.

Comment: is about states ? I just want not render the whole component again and again